# Multiple events for one delegate

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

NOTE;  Posting Pseudo Code Example...  See Example Text below ( I told you this would be a hilarious mess ! )

```
Class Enter
{

  public event EnterDelegate EnterDelegateEvent;

  public event ExitDelegate ExitDelegateEvent;

  public Enter(EventEventArgs e)
  {
     // do something

     EnterOrder(e);

     ExitEventArgs ev = new ExitEventArgs(string ticker, double prices.. etc);
     ExitEvent(ev);

      // update order status etc.
  }

  private double EnterOrder()
  {
     double ent = 0.00
     if (EnterDelegateEvent != null)
     {
         ent = EnterDelegateEvent(this, e);
         return ent;
     }

     else { return e.lo;  }
  }

   public double ExitEvent(ExitEventArgs e)
   {
     // do something
     ExitEvent(ev);
   }

   private double ExitEvent()
   {
     double ext = 0.00
     if (ExitDelegateEvent != null)
     {
         ext = ExitDelegateEvent(this, e);
         return ext;
     }

     else { return e.Hi;  }
   }

}  // end Enter Class



Class EventHandlers
{
   public double SendEnter(EventArgs e)
   {
       // send enter to order server here
       return price;
   }
   public double SendExit(EventArgs e)
   {
       // send exit to order server here
       return price
   }

}


Orders Class
{

   Enter ent = new Enter();

   public GetOrders()
   {
      // get order data
      // create order event
      EnterEventArgs ev = new EnterEventArgs(ticker, price, data...etc);
      ent.Enter(ev);

    }
}

Orders.aspx.cs
{

    EventHandlers evt = new EventHandlers();
    Enter ent = new Enter();
    Orders ord = new Orders();

    Private void login()
    {
       // log into Orders Server
       ent.EnterDelegateEvent += EnterDelegate(evt.SendEnter);
       ent.ExitDelegateEvent += ExitDelegate(evt.SendExit);

    }

    private void logout()
    {
        // delete / remove delegate event handlers;
    }

    // initiate orders example event
    private void btnclick_GetOrders()
    {
       ord.GetOrders();
    }

}
```

In addition to running GetOrders, above, I also need to run another set of orders from GetBackTest().. This needs to be simultaneous at times so when it runs the EnterOrder() routine the EventDelegate needs to return if (EventDelegate == null) { return e.prices; }

Instead of using the EventHandler method...

```
Class Backtest
{
    Enter ent = new Enter();

   // kickoff enter order just as Orders Class does

    // this class needs to NOT use the Event Delegate as Orders class does

}
```

Is there a straightforward way to turn the DelegateEvents on and off and make sure that only one of them is instantiated ?? IF I turn the Delegate events as Static, the the backtest class will use the eventhandler methods.

Comment: I think you should give more context about your situation. maybe give a small example on the scenario you want to achieve.

Comment: if you & everyone can learn from `hilarious mess` it's good for everyone. post it anyway.

Comment: You need to explain yourself using steps/pseudocode.  Your first paragraph is one long sentence that is nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: How you send dummy data?

Comment: Okay, The pseudo code is posted,  I hope I did not further confuse matters.. !!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really didn't have to use event delegate however using other parameters to routes events required adding them and using them throughout or using existing and causing havoc, so to route the trade events using event delegates, I just added:

```
 EventDelegateName += new DelegateName(eventhandler); // to top of orders.cs

 EventDelegateName -= new DelegateName(eventhandler); // to bottom of orders.cs
```

so when backtest.cs ran the (Event == null) ran the alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the scenario you're describing, but events and delegates can be a little tricky at first.  I would suggest reading up on some .NET event tutorials:

- Events - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx
- Delegates - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(VS.71).aspx
- Another tutorial - http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest working out a flow diagram first.  It seems to me what exactly you want to do is not clear.  Maybe with a flow diagram (or some other way of documenting what the system does) it would be.

I'm not even sure you need delegates for this problem the way you describe it.